# StackOverflowError while using Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a class that all data stored. I use `ArrayList<ModelHomeListing>` to process it. I need to store it in SharedPreferences but I cannot use it without Gson because there are a lot of type of variables in the model.

I use the code below while storing:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(listings_items, new TypeToken<ArrayList<ModelHomeListing>>() {}.getType());
editor.putString("listing_items", json);
editor.commit();
```

...and I fetch it with below:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = sharedPrefs.getString("listing_items", null);
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ModelHomeListing>>() {}.getType();
items = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

However I get `StackOverflowError` if I use gson version **2.3.1**. If I change the version to **1.7.1** on gradle, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: circular reference error
    Offending field: adapter
    Offending object: preserveType: false, type: class...
```

Which version should I use and how can I prevent this error?

ModelHomeListing class:

```
public class ModelHomeListing {

    private Context context;

    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String title_slug;
    private String description;
        // location
        private String location_country;
        private String location_city;
        private String location_district;
        private String location_neighborhood;
        private double location_latitude;
        private double location_longitude;
        private ArrayList<String> location_vicinities;
        // properties
        private String properties_home_property_type;
        private int properties_home_number_of_rooms;
        private int properties_home_living_rooms;
        private int properties_home_bathrooms;
        private int properties_square_meter;
        private String properties_building_age;
        private int properties_number_of_floors;
        private String properties_home_floor_number;
        private String properties_building_condition;
        private int properties_monthly_fee;
        private String properties_home_usage_condition;
        private String properties_heating;
        private String properties_fuel_type;
        private ArrayList<String> properties_home_inside_features;
        private ArrayList<String> properties_home_outside_features;
        private int properties_rental_income;
        private String properties_applicable_to_loan;
        // price
        private int price_amount;
        private String price_currency;
    private String category;
    private int created_at;
    private int updated_at;
    private String sale_rent;
    private ArrayList<String> photos_thumbnail;
    private ArrayList<String> photos_middle;
    private ArrayList<String> photos_large;
    private String status;
    private int view_count;
    private boolean doping;
    private boolean favorite;

    private SharedPreferences sp;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public ModelHomeListing(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        id = 0;
        title = "";
        title_slug = "";
        description = "";
        location_country = "";
        location_city = "";
        location_district = "";
        location_neighborhood = "";
        location_latitude = 0.0;
        location_longitude = 0.0;
        location_vicinities = new ArrayList<String>();
        properties_home_property_type = "";
        properties_home_number_of_rooms = 0;
        properties_home_living_rooms = 0;
        properties_home_bathrooms = 0;
        properties_square_meter = 0;
        properties_building_age = "";
        properties_number_of_floors = 0;
        properties_home_floor_number = "";
        properties_building_condition = "";
        properties_monthly_fee = 0;
        properties_home_usage_condition = "";
        properties_heating = "";
        properties_fuel_type = "";
        properties_home_inside_features = new ArrayList<String>();
        properties_home_outside_features = new ArrayList<String>();
        properties_rental_income = 0;
        properties_applicable_to_loan = "";
        price_amount = 0;
        price_currency = "";
        category = "";
        created_at = 0;
        updated_at = 0;
        sale_rent = "";
        photos_thumbnail = new ArrayList<String>();
        photos_middle = new ArrayList<String>();
        photos_large = new ArrayList<String>();
        status = "";
        view_count = 0;
        doping = false;
        favorite = false;

        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        editor = sp.edit();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle_slug() {
        return title_slug;
    }

    public void setTitle_slug(String title_slug) {
        this.title_slug = title_slug;
    }

    public String getLocation_city() {
        return location_city;
    }

    public void setLocation_city(String location_city) {
        this.location_city = location_city;
    }

    public String getSale_rent() {
        return sale_rent;
    }

    public void setSale_rent(String sale_rent) {
        this.sale_rent = sale_rent;
    }

    public int getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public void setCreated_at(int created_at) {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }

    public String getLocation_district() {
        return location_district;
    }

    public void setLocation_district(String location_district) {
        this.location_district = location_district;
    }

    public String getLocation_neighborhood() {
        return location_neighborhood;
    }

    public void setLocation_neighborhood(String location_neighborhood) {
        this.location_neighborhood = location_neighborhood;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getLocation_vicinities() {
        return location_vicinities;
    }

    public void setLocation_vicinities(ArrayList<String> location_vicinities) {
        this.location_vicinities = location_vicinities;
    }

    public String getProperties_home_property_type() {
        return properties_home_property_type;
    }

    public void setProperties_home_property_type(String properties_home_property_type) {
        this.properties_home_property_type = properties_home_property_type;
    }

    public int getProperties_home_number_of_rooms() {
        return properties_home_number_of_rooms;
    }

    public void setProperties_home_number_of_rooms(int properties_home_number_of_rooms) {
        this.properties_home_number_of_rooms = properties_home_number_of_rooms;
    }

    public int getProperties_square_meter() {
        return properties_square_meter;
    }

    public void setProperties_square_meter(int properties_square_meter) {
        this.properties_square_meter = properties_square_meter;
    }

    public int getProperties_number_of_floors() {
        return properties_number_of_floors;
    }

    public void setProperties_number_of_floors(int properties_number_of_floors) {
        this.properties_number_of_floors = properties_number_of_floors;
    }

    public int getPrice_amount() {
        return price_amount;
    }

    public void setPrice_amount(int price_amount) {
        this.price_amount = price_amount;
    }

    public String getPrice_currency() {
        return price_currency;
    }

    public void setPrice_currency(String price_currency) {
        this.price_currency = price_currency;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public boolean isFavorite() {
        return sp.getBoolean("listing" + String.valueOf(this.id), false);
    }

    public void setFavorite(boolean favorite) {
        editor.putBoolean("listing" + String.valueOf(this.id), favorite);
        editor.commit();
        this.favorite = favorite;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPhotos_thumbnail() {
        return photos_thumbnail;
    }

    public void setPhotos_thumbnail(ArrayList<String> photos_thumbnail) {
        this.photos_thumbnail = photos_thumbnail;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPhotos_middle() {
        return photos_middle;
    }

    public void setPhotos_middle(ArrayList<String> photos_middle) {
        this.photos_middle = photos_middle;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPhotos_large() {
        return photos_large;
    }

    public void setPhotos_large(ArrayList<String> photos_large) {
        this.photos_large = photos_large;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getLocation_country() {
        return location_country;
    }

    public void setLocation_country(String location_country) {
        this.location_country = location_country;
    }

    public double getLocation_latitude() {
        return location_latitude;
    }

    public void setLocation_latitude(double location_latitude) {
        this.location_latitude = location_latitude;
    }

    public double getLocation_longitude() {
        return location_longitude;
    }

    public void setLocation_longitude(double location_longitude) {
        this.location_longitude = location_longitude;
    }

    public int getProperties_home_living_rooms() {
        return properties_home_living_rooms;
    }

    public void setProperties_home_living_rooms(int properties_home_living_rooms) {
        this.properties_home_living_rooms = properties_home_living_rooms;
    }

    public int getProperties_home_bathrooms() {
        return properties_home_bathrooms;
    }

    public void setProperties_home_bathrooms(int properties_home_bathrooms) {
        this.properties_home_bathrooms = properties_home_bathrooms;
    }

    public String getProperties_building_age() {
        return properties_building_age;
    }

    public void setProperties_building_age(String properties_building_age) {
        this.properties_building_age = properties_building_age;
    }

    public String getProperties_home_floor_number() {
        return properties_home_floor_number;
    }

    public void setProperties_home_floor_number(String properties_home_floor_number) {
        this.properties_home_floor_number = properties_home_floor_number;
    }

    public String getProperties_building_condition() {
        return properties_building_condition;
    }

    public void setProperties_building_condition(String properties_building_condition) {
        this.properties_building_condition = properties_building_condition;
    }

    public int getProperties_monthly_fee() {
        return properties_monthly_fee;
    }

    public void setProperties_monthly_fee(int properties_monthly_fee) {
        this.properties_monthly_fee = properties_monthly_fee;
    }

    public String getProperties_home_usage_condition() {
        return properties_home_usage_condition;
    }

    public void setProperties_home_usage_condition(String properties_home_usage_condition) {
        this.properties_home_usage_condition = properties_home_usage_condition;
    }

    public String getProperties_heating() {
        return properties_heating;
    }

    public void setProperties_heating(String properties_heating) {
        this.properties_heating = properties_heating;
    }

    public String getProperties_fuel_type() {
        return properties_fuel_type;
    }

    public void setProperties_fuel_type(String properties_fuel_type) {
        this.properties_fuel_type = properties_fuel_type;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getProperties_home_inside_features() {
        return properties_home_inside_features;
    }

    public void setProperties_home_inside_features(ArrayList<String> properties_home_inside_features) {
        this.properties_home_inside_features = properties_home_inside_features;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getProperties_home_outside_features() {
        return properties_home_outside_features;
    }

    public void setProperties_home_outside_features(ArrayList<String> properties_home_outside_features) {
        this.properties_home_outside_features = properties_home_outside_features;
    }

    public int getProperties_rental_income() {
        return properties_rental_income;
    }

    public void setProperties_rental_income(int properties_rental_income) {
        this.properties_rental_income = properties_rental_income;
    }

    public String getProperties_applicable_to_loan() {
        return properties_applicable_to_loan;
    }

    public void setProperties_applicable_to_loan(String properties_applicable_to_loan) {
        this.properties_applicable_to_loan = properties_applicable_to_loan;
    }

    public int getUpdated_at() {
        return updated_at;
    }

    public void setUpdated_at(int updated_at) {
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getView_count() {
        return view_count;
    }

    public void setView_count(int view_count) {
        this.view_count = view_count;
    }

    public boolean isDoping() {
        return doping;
    }

    public void setDoping(boolean doping) {
        this.doping = doping;
    }

}
```

Comment: ModelHomeListing is too long. The class just has a few global variables and getters and setters of them.

Comment: Looks like exists some recursive reference...

Comment: Can you give an example about where it is?

Comment: There is no field called `adapter` in ModelHomeListing class.

Comment: The `SharedPreferences`, `SharedPreferences.Editor`, and `Context` members are most likely causing your problem.

Comment: @halilkaya on a side-note: you should probably split this object into smaller objects - this is a crazy amount of variables for one class and will be hard to maintain/change when time comes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That would probably happen if you have a circular reference.

Does ModelHomeListing reference your parent object?

If yes, it goes into an infinite loop when serializing the parent and child collections and that overflows your stack.

Try deleting the context from constructor of serialize class also.

```
public ModelHomeListing(Context context) {
}
```

Change to

```
public ModelHomeListing() {
}
```

Or if you really want to deal with context try to make it static .